# Using bash check which Google-Chrome release channel I have installed

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04, google-chrome

Using `google-chrome --version`, it shows me the version but in my case I don't care, I just want some `bash` command to show me inside the output only the string: `google-chrome-stable` , or `google-chrome-beta`, or `google-chrome-dev`, or `google-chrome-canary`; giving priority to the most stable release channel if there are multiple channels installed on the computer.

How do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this solution in a slightly different environment.
Plain version output:

```
$ chromium-browser --version
BlueALSA detected - Disabling audio sandbox
Chromium 92.0.4515.98 Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10
```

We want to get rid of error and warning messages, and select the version string.
So, redirect stderr to /dev/null, and use awk to grab the second field.

```
$ chromium-browser --version 2>/dev/null | awk '/^Chromium/{print $2}'
92.0.4515.98
```

Modify this for your situation and you're done.

Comment: <Using `google-chrome --version`, it shows me the version but in my case I don't care> That's just what I have said I don't need, I need to get release channel (stable, beta, dev, canary).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.